# ¿Porque me sale: [Warning] this decimal constant is unsigned only in ISO C90? en C++?

Tags: c++, bucle-for

Hola he creado este programa que ha de probar diferentes números entre 3x10^9 hasta 4x10^9 hasta encontrar el valor que cumple la función y guardarlo. He probado de hacerlo con un esquema de búsqueda y después un for que vaya variando el número. Pero a la hora de compilar me sale: "[Warning] this decimal constant is unsigned only in ISO C90"
Y cuando muestro por pantalla la variable "i" para ver por que numero va, me sale un numero negativo (adjunto imagen)
[image: Valor de "i" que sale negativo]

Dejo aquí el codigo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int main (){
    double mu_sol=1.326663*pow(10,20), v_exces=7615.077, mu_jupiter=1.2660994*pow(10,17), r_o_j=7.1492*pow(10,7);
    double v_r=5151.02, v_t=7450.49;
    double auxiliar, r_a=10.5*1.496*pow(10,11), r_p;
    auxiliar=(v_exces*v_exces)/mu_jupiter;
    double v_j_tan=13059.09;
    double auxiliar_2=0;
        cout << v_t << "   " << v_r << r_o_j << "  " << mu_jupiter<< endl;
        bool trobat=false;
    while (trobat==false){
            for(long int i=3039999999; i<=4000000000; i++){
            double delta;
            delta=2*asin(1*pow(1+auxiliar*i,-1));
            auxiliar_2=(2*mu_sol)/sqrt(pow(cos(delta)*v_r-sin(delta)*v_t,2)+pow(sin(delta)*v_r+cos(delta)*v_t+v_j_tan,2));
            cout <<  i << endl;
            cout << "hola" << endl;
        if (auxiliar_2==r_a){
            trobat=true;
            r_p=i;}
            else trobat=false;}
    }
    
    
    cout << r_p << endl;
    cout << "final" << endl;

    
}
```

Comment: debes declarar `i` de tipo `unsigned long int`

Comment: Muchas gracias ahora sí funciona

Comment: @abulafia ¿no tendría que declarar también las constantes como `ul`?

Comment: @SJuan76 Pues para estar del lado de la seguridad, mejor sí. Bien visto. Es decir, escribir `3039999999UL` y `4000000000UL`

Answer (score 0):

3039999999 --> 1011 0101 0011 0010 1011 0111 1111 1111

Si el tamaño de long es 64 bits, **este número es negativo** (el primer bit es 1, mira "complemento a dos")

Puedes solucionarlo definiendo el tipo de `i` como unsigned long int, que usa los mismo 64 bits pero usa "binario natural".